# Postgres- delete record not existing in array as value referenced in another table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I am trying to write an SQL query with **PostgreSQL** where I want to `DELETE` `team_member_tag` table record no longer presented in the array of `$tags`. The parameter is found in the `tag` table.

`tag` table:

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 3742 | first-tag |
| 3743 | second-tag |

`team_member_tag` table:

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89263 | 68893 | 3742 |
| 89264 | 68893 | 3743 |

The catch is that I should be referenced by the `ID` value and it can be found by the `slug` value.

My example:

```
    $tags = ['first-tag'];

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    
            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare('
                DELETE FROM team_member_tag tmt
                WHERE t.slug = :tag NOT IN
                (SELECT t.id FROM tag t)
             ');

            $stmt->bindValue('tag', $tag);

            $stmt->executeQuery();
        }
```

or

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    
            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare('
                 DELETE FROM team_member_tag tmt
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT t.id
                 FROM tag t
                 WHERE t.slug = :tag)
             ');

            $stmt->bindValue('tag', $tag);

            $stmt->executeQuery();
        }
```

In this example, the `second-tag` reference should be deleted from the `team_member_tag` table.

My SQL examples are not working so I need help to find it by `slug` value in the `tag` table and delete it in `team_member_tag` if it *does not exist* in the array of values.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My SQL examples are not working so I need help to find it by slug value in tag table and delete it in team_member_tag if it does not exist in the array of values.. @GMB

Comment: why do you bind the member id?

Comment: *My SQL examples are not working*; what is the problem? Are you getting an error, which one exactly (pls update the question directly with the entire error message)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get all tag_ig fromthe tag table, that must be deleted

```
$tags = ['first-tag'];

foreach ($tags as $tag) {

        $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare('
            DELETE FROM team_member_tag tmt
            WHERE tmt.tag_id NOT IN
            (SELECT t.id FROM tag t WHERE t.slug = :tag )
         ');

        $stmt->bindValue('tag', $tag);

        $stmt->executeQuery();
    }
```

Here you can see that it works

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "slug" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tag
  ("id", "slug")
VALUES
  ('3742', 'first-tag'),
  ('3743', 'second-tag');

CREATE TABLE team_member_tag (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "team_member_id" INTEGER,
  "tag_id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO team_member_tag
  ("id", "team_member_id", "tag_id")
VALUES
  ('89263', '68893', '3742'),
  ('89264', '68893', '3743');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 2
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 2
> ```

```
DELETE FROM team_member_tag tmt
                WHERE tmt.tag_id NOT IN
                (SELECT t.id FROM tag t WHERE t.slug = 'first-tag' )
```

> ```
> DELETE 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM team_member_tag
```

| id | team_member_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89263 | 68893 | 3742 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pL52M2ga)